# Could not install Ubuntu 16.04 using USB

Tags: boot, uefi

I've made a bootable USB to install Ubuntu 16.04. I tried the USB on my Macbook to make sure that the USB works.
Now I use the USB for my new HP Z640 PC. I change the BIOS setting so that booting from the USB is the first priority. The PC recognizes the USB and it shows options including "try Ubuntu", "install Ubuntu", etc,. I have tried both "try Ubuntu" and "install Ubuntu" and in both cases, it shows the following errors:

```
efi: requested map not found
efi: Failed to lookup EFI memory descriptor
```

I've tried to change the BIOS setting but it never works.
Could you please suggest a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Which method did you use to make the USB bootable?

Comment: I've used rufus (Windows) and dd command (OS X) to create the USB and both methods are not working.

Comment: Try using "GPT partition scheme for UEFI computer" as the partition scheme in Rufus

Comment: I've tried the three options in Rufus but it doesn't help. Remember that I've tried the USB with my Macbook and it has no problems.